# Replace all missing value based on other column value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, replace, na

Here is a dummy data.frame to show what I am trying to achieve :

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
           type = c("a","b","a","c","b"),
           value1 = c(10,NA,NA,NA,35),
           value2 = c(13,NA,NA,NA,39),
           value3 = c(8,NA,NA,NA,38),
           value4 = c(10,NA,NA,NA,25),
           value5 = c(15,NA,NA,NA,44),
           value6 = c(5,NA,NA,NA,24),
           value7 = c(11,NA,NA,NA,42))
```

| id | type | value1 | … | value7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 10 |  | 11 |
| 2 | b | NA |  | NA |
| 3 | a | NA |  | NA |
| 4 | c | NA |  | NA |
| 5 | b | 35 |  | 42 |

The goal would be to replace the NA in the columns **value1** to **value7** with a value varying based on the **type**.

So for example all NA value for type "a" would be replaced by 12, for type "b" it would be by 38 and for type "c" it would be replace by 50.

So the desired result would look like this :

| id | type | value1 | … | value7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 10 |  | 11 |
| 2 | b | 38 |  | 38 |
| 3 | a | 12 |  | 12 |
| 4 | c | 50 |  | 50 |
| 5 | b | 35 |  | 42 |

Any ideas on how to get this results?

I know I can get this result by doing something like this :

```
df %>% 
mutate(value1 = case_when(type == "a" ~ coalesce(value1,12), 
                          type == "b" ~ coalesce(value1,38), 
                          T ~ coalesce(value1,50)))
```

And do the same thing for all the other columns, but in reality I have way more than 7 columns to change. So this method would be very unpractical.

I’ve been searching for a function that would allow me to replace all NA in row but so far nothing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `across` to apply the function to many columns (e.g. "not column 1 or 2"), and then use coalesce and case_match to replace NAs based on a set of rules.

```
df |>
  mutate(across(-(1:2), ~ coalesce(
      .x,
      case_match(
        type,
        "a" ~ 12,
        "b" ~ 38,
        "c" ~ 50
      )
    )
  ))
```

Result

```
  id type value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6 value7
1  1    a     10     13      8     10     15      5     11
2  2    b     38     38     38     38     38     38     38
3  3    a     12     12     12     12     12     12     12
4  4    c     50     50     50     50     50     50     50
5  5    b     35     39     38     25     44     24     42
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different approach using `case_when` and `coalesce` in different positions:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(-c(1,2), \(x) {
    case_when(
      type == "a" ~ coalesce(x, 12),
      type == "b" ~ coalesce(x, 38),
      .default = coalesce(x, 50)
    )
  }))


 id type value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6 value7
1  1    a     10     13      8     10     15      5     11
2  2    b     38     38     38     38     38     38     38
3  3    a     12     12     12     12     12     12     12
4  4    c     50     50     50     50     50     50     50
5  5    b     35     39     38     25     44     24     42
```

Answer (score 0):

So just for a little base R, you could do something like

```
x <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
           type = c("a","b","a","c","b"),
           value1 = c(10,NA,NA,NA,35),
           value2 = c(13,NA,NA,NA,39),
           value3 = c(8,NA,NA,NA,38),
           value4 = c(10,NA,NA,NA,25),
           value5 = c(15,NA,NA,NA,44),
           value6 = c(5,NA,NA,NA,24),
           value7 = c(11,NA,NA,NA,42))

replacements <- c("a" = 12, "b" = 38, "c" = 50)
variable_names <- names(x)[-c(1,2)]

for (i in 1:length(variable_names)){
     current_na <- is.na(x[variable_names[i]])
     x[[variable_names[i]]][current_na] <-
          replacements[x$type[current_na]]
}
```

If I were running this many times, I would take the `for` and rewrite into an apply structure but if I'm only doing it once I might not since I think it is pretty readable.

Answer (score 0):

How to replace missing values with constants based on column another column

github
[Replace all missing value based on other column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77026943/replace-all-missing-value-based-on-other-column-value)

SOLUTIONS

```
   0 WPS/SAS (does not work in dropdown to wps use notepad++?)                                    
     Uses peek and poke. Two of the most powerfull assembler instructions are load and store.     
   1 wps no sql                                                                                   
   2 wps r                                                                                        
     https://stackoverflow.com/users/13321647/tarjae                                              
   3 Related reps on end
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace missing values with constants based on column another column

Wrong link to github

https://github.com/rogerjdeangelis/utl-replace-missing-values-with-constants-based-on-column-another-column